# Delta modulation (DM) signals

Tags: signal, modulation, demodulation, integrator, digital-modulation

Trying to understand this circuit. Will this produce a representation similar to example in second image (if U_inf is the sine wave "original") ?

Assuming that, I expect U_DM to look like the "modulated" signal. How would the signal look like at point A and B ?

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

I'll add that the circuit ([HPS modulation board](http://hps-systemtechnik.com/4280-modulation-board-2/?lang=en)) was tested with the following outputs. Increasing the U_s voltage level changed the signal to 2nd image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Get LTSpice (free) and simulate it for the best answer.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like Delta Modulation with a sample frequency that's too low or an integrator that's not fast enough.

Comment: Actually, no, you'd expect a triangle wave with straight lines at the integrator output not a staircase like that.

Comment: A would be purple and B would be light blue. (Whether B would be smooth or staircase as shown, depends on the details of that switch)

Comment: @Finbarr: "sample freq. too low"; May you elaborate the thought process on this. What details make this indication?

Comment: From a sinewave in, you'd expect to see an output which has relatively long sequences of 1s or 0s where the input is changing rapidly (up and down the slopes) and quicker alternation of 1s and 0s where it changes more slowly (at the peaks). To get a squarewave out, you're either not giving the output the chance to change quickly enough or the integrator can't keep up with your input waveform.

Comment: @BrianDrummond To get the output shown as "modulated" the switch would have to be a D-type latch, wouldn't it?

Comment: @bretddog You want the slope of the triangle waveform to match the slope of the highest frequency sinewave - you can see it's about half as steep as it should be - to accurately reproduce the sinewave. That means either sample twice as often, or double the step size.

Comment: If those rotary controls next to the squarewave generator adjust the signal levels, I suggest you go back to the settings in the first image and then turn down the level of the 500Hz signal and see what happens as you do so. As it doesn't look like you can increase the slope of the integrator, the alternative is to reduce the slope of the signal by making it smaller.

Comment: @Finbarr: I don't have access to this setup anymore. But understand now better why I got this output.